# Bucketize real valued Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, mapping, slice

I have a matrix like this:

```
tf_ent = tf.Variable([   [9.96,    8.65,    0.8,    0.1 ],
                         [0.7,     8.33,    0  ,    0   ],
                         [0.9,     0,       6,      7.33],
                         [6.60,    0,       3,      5.5 ],
                         [9.49,    0.,      0,      0   ],
                         [0.4,     8.45,    0,      0.2 ],
                         [0.3,     0,       5.82,   8.28]])
```

I want to get an output in which the weight in the same range get the same `number`.

To put it another way, This number is a good representative of the `weight range` in the matrix.

So my ideal output could be something like this:

```
                [[5,    5,    1,    1],
                 [1,    5,    0,    0],
                 [1,    0,    6,    5],
                 [4,    0,    2,    3],
                 [5,    0.,   0,    0],
                 [1,    5,    0,    1],
                 [1,    0,    3,    5]]
```

In this case I mapped with this condition(consider that i have my mapping):

```
range(0.1, 1) -> 1
range( 1, 3) -> 2
range( 3, 5) -> 3
range(5, 7) -> 4
range (7, 10) -> 5
```

firstly I tried with `tf.histogram_fixed_width_bins` but it did not give me the expected result:
this is my code:

```
value_ranges = [0, 10.0]
nbins = 5
new_f_w_t = tf.histogram_fixed_width_bins(tf_ent, value_ranges, nbins)
print(new_f_w_t)
```

and this is the output of this code:

```
output= [[4 4 0 0]
        [0 4 0 0]
        [0 0 3 3]
        [3 0 1 2]
        [4 0 0 0]
        [0 4 0 0]
        [0 0 2 4]]
```

output more like getting an equivalent integer of those float numbers rather than considering any range.

How can I get a dynamic mapping of the matrix in an efficient way?

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to a `np.digitize` operation. You can use `math_ops._bucketize`:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops

bins = [0.1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 10]
new_f_w_t = math_ops._bucketize(tf_ent, boundaries=bins)

new_f_w_t.numpy()
array([[5, 5, 1, 1],
       [1, 5, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 4, 5],
       [4, 0, 3, 4],
       [5, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 5, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 4, 5]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, just a quick question, why we don't have this `op` in `tensorflow` itself? like calling`tf.math_ops._bucketize`?

Comment: @sariii Can't speak for the devs, but perhaps they didn't see it as being a very commonly used function, or believed that the `histogram*` methods would be enough.

Comment: This is weird I am getting matrix of zero! `[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]`

Comment: @sariii Are your inputs and bins the same as described here? I ran this on TensorFlow 2.0 and it worked fine.

Comment: Yea Im just copy pasting, maybe problem with my tensorflow, I look into it, :) your approach seems what I want, thank you  again.

Comment: it was tensorflow issue, Thank you so much:)

Comment: Can you please explain about the algorithm behind the `bucketize`? how does it know `9.96` should be mapped to `5` but not `10` ?

Comment: @sariii assuming `bins` is a sorted array, bucketize returns the index (position) in the array that 9.96 should be inserted into (which is 5 in this case). Think `searchsorted`.

Comment: So in this case, because we have `4 elements` per `row` always the biggest numbers will be assigned to `5`?. if not, I still did not get it :|

Comment: @sariii Um, no. Ask yourself, at which index will you insert 9.96 into `bins`? Repeat this for each element in the array. This is what `bucketize` does.

Comment: Another example: At which index will you insert `2` into `[1, 3, 5]`? Between 1 and 3, which is index 1.

Comment: Oh now I got it.  then I need to change the `bin range`. Thank you so much:)

Answer (score 0):

The `tf.searchsorted()` call can also be used for this purpose, which avoids calling the hidden _bucketize function. You have to tile the bins to match the dimensions of the input values, though.

For example:

```
bins = tf.tile([[0.1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 10]], (tf_ent.shape[0], 1))
new_f_w_t = tf.searchsorted(bins, tf_ent, side="right")
```